# materialize compass watch shows error on default

Tags: compass, materialize

I am using ruby 2.1.2 ,Compass 1.0.1, Sass 3.4.21 (Selective Steve).

While my config.rb file contains

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

I haven't changed the default file that i downloaded from materialize css. compass watch generates the following errors
error sass/materialize.scss

```
(/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/selector/abstract_sequence.rb:96:in `block in _specificity': undefined method `specificity' for [:not(.btn)]:Array)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's running with the same problem.

There was problem in the latest version of Sass by removing and installing the 3.4.16 version the problem was fixed.